# iOS Firebase - how to check if user not logged in

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I wan't to check if the user is't logged into my app.
If that happend, i wan't to redirect him to notLoggedView or verifyAccuontView.

At this moment code looks like this and if user not created i can't get into notLoggedView.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(true);

        let user = Auth.auth().currentUser;

        if (user == nil) {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "notLoggedView", sender: self);
        }
    }
```

This code works same as above (like user exist, but firebase accounts is empty)

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(true);

        if let user = Auth.auth().currentUser {
            // action when account exist
        } else {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "notLoggedView", sender: self);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    Auth.auth()!.addStateDidChangeListener() { auth, user in
        if user != nil {
            self.switchStoryboard()
        }
    }
}
```

or You can check directly

```
if Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid != nil {

   //user is logged in

    }else{
     //user is not logged in
    }
```

for Signup you use

```
Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: emailField.text!, password: passwordField.text!) { user, error in
  if error == nil {
    // 3
    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: self.textFieldLoginEmail.text!,
                       password: self.textFieldLoginPassword.text!)
  }
}
```

Comment: First way, after create account i redirected to not logged page, its normal? i need to sign in first after sign up?

Comment: If there are no errors, the user account has been created, you still need to authenticate this new user, so call signIn(withEmail:password:), again passing in the supplied email and password.

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/3-firebase-tutorial-getting-started
check out this link for clarity

Comment: Okey, last question, if i created account and sign up i need to sign up every time when launching the app or the app remember it (or how to make it)?

Comment: app will remember it

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if there is no user logged in, check `currentUser` directly.

```
let user = Auth.auth().currentUser;
if (user == nil) {
    // there is no user signed in when user is nil
}
```

Also be sure see the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user) for more information.

Comment: @iSheep check out my answer.. i hope it will help you